# Image viewer for large files in Java

Tags: java, image, large-files

We need to be able to load large (typically >10,000px in one dimension but potential larger) images into Java.  The user will need to zoom/pan the image and then click points which the program then uses to make distance measurements.

As always I'd rather not reinvent the wheel so would like a library that will handle reading popular formats (JPG and TIF), but also take care of memory handling, tiling etc.  I'm assuming proper image editing programs like GIMP and Photoshop don't read large images directly into memory but rather read subsets of the data as needed?

The solution needs to be open source as this is an academic project. It also needs to be cross-platform so native libs are out unless they are available for Windows, Linux and OSX.